# Potential leak check in iPhone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//responseData = nil;

NSMutableDictionary* json =[[responseString JSONValue] retain];
[responseString release];

NSLog(@"Sample message %d",[json retainCount]);
```

Here m getting retain count is 2, can any one help in this how can i track, this retain count.
The problem is when i write the following code the app is crashing.

```
 [json release];
```

app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

**retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.**

You can't use `retainCount` to try and determine when something needs to be released.

In that code, it isn't clear why it is crashing.  Post the backtrace of the crash.